# Best way to handle big dataset in R

Tags: r, bigdata, ff, r-bigmemory

I have to run some regression models and descriptives on a big dataset. I have a folder of around 500 files (update: txt files) which I would like to merge, and are in total 250GB.

I know how to merge all files from a folder, but although I am running it on a 128RAM server, I keep getting out of memory.

I am looking for any tips/advice on how to load in/merge these files in a manageable way (if possible) way using R.I have been looking into packages such as "ff" and "bigmemory", will these offer me a solution?

Comment: don't know what you are using to read your data, but read_csv (from readr) and fread (from data.table) are usually faster than read.csv or read.table

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the ff and biglm packages. The latter allows you to run a regression on the entire dataset stored on disk (using ff), by loading smaller chunks of it in RAM. Use `read.table.ffdf()` to convert the separate txt files to an ff file on disk. See the example in the help file for `chunk.ffdf()` how to run a regression using `biglm()`.